# Android app keeps throwing java NullPointerException and crashes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

AM newbie to android development i have recycler view on one of my fragment that i add items to it , the problem comes when i try to add itesm from a dirrent fragment it throws a java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference

**Here is my function to add items to it**

```
public void fillNotification(int mImage, String mtext, String mtext2, String mDate, Activity activity)
    {
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = activity.findViewById (R.id.notificationsRecycler);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (getContext ());
        mAdapter = new NotificationAdapter (notimodels);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        notimodels.add (0,new NotificationModel (mImage,mtext,mtext2,mDate));
    }
```

**on Accessing it from outside the fragment**

```
 notimodels = new ArrayList<> ();
                                    NotificationFragmentCict notificationFragmentCict =new NotificationFragmentCict ();
                                    notificationFragmentCict.fillNotification (R.drawable.snal, "Snal", "your cleared","min",getActivity ());
```

But it keeps throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

`activity.findViewById (R.id.notificationsRecycler)` can only find `notificationsRecycler` in the layout of  your activity. Are you sure you have `R.id.notificationsRecycler` in the layout of your activity?

As you have mentioned, you may have `R.id.notificationsRecycler` in the layout of your fragment.

If I guess right, you have to get `mRecyclerView` this way:

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.notificationsRecycler);
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: that problem is accessing it from other fragment, not the fragment that has the recyclerview

Comment: Could you please explain it in more details? I am trying to understand what have happened, but I cannot.

Comment: okay i have one fragment that has a recycler view , now i want to add items in the recycler view from another fragment which has no recycler view , thats why i created that function in order to try to add items from another fragments

Comment: I think I get the point. You have one activity, which contains two fragments. One fragment wants to communicate with the other fragment by sending some data. They have to communicate by the activity they stayed in. This doc [https://developer.android.google.cn/training/basics/fragments/communicating](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/basics/fragments/communicating) will help you.

Comment: At the last of the doc, there is a demo provided, which you can download and reference.

Comment: let me try brother